# Pandas group by rolling standard deviation

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to calculate the standard deviation of a value, by group.
I am getting unexpected results. Can someone help?

```
from numpy import nan
df = {'value': {1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: 0.1, 11: 0.3, 12: 0.6, 13: 0.2, 14: -0.1, 15: 0.2}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
df['group'] = [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
df['rolling_std'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].rolling(3).std().values
df.head(15)

value   group   rolling_std
1   NaN 1   NaN
2   NaN 2   NaN
3   NaN 1   NaN
4   NaN 2   NaN
5   NaN 1   NaN
6   NaN 2   NaN
7   NaN 1   NaN
8   NaN 2   0.057735  # here I expect NaN since all values from group 2 are NaN so far
9   NaN 1   NaN
10  0.1 2   NaN
11  0.3 1   NaN
12  0.6 2   NaN
13  0.2 1   NaN
14  -0.1    2   NaN
15  0.2 1   0.360555
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df['rolling_std'] = df.groupby('group')['value'].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(3).std())
```

Or remove first level of MultiIndex for align by index values, because if use `.values` it assign numpy array with different order:

```
df['rolling_std'] = (df.groupby('group')['value']
                      .rolling(3)
                      .std()
                      .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
print (df)


    value  group  rolling_std
1     NaN      1          NaN
2     NaN      2          NaN
3     NaN      1          NaN
4     NaN      2          NaN
5     NaN      1          NaN
6     NaN      2          NaN
7     NaN      1          NaN
8     NaN      2          NaN
9     NaN      1          NaN
10    0.1      2          NaN
11    0.3      1          NaN
12    0.6      2          NaN
13    0.2      1          NaN
14   -0.1      2     0.360555
15    0.2      1     0.057735
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('group')['value']
                      .rolling(3)
                      .std())

group    
1      1          NaN
       3          NaN
       5          NaN
       7          NaN
       9          NaN
       11         NaN
       13         NaN
       15    0.057735
2      2          NaN
       4          NaN
       6          NaN
       8          NaN
       10         NaN
       12         NaN
       14    0.360555
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

---

```
print (df.groupby('group')['value']
                      .rolling(3)
                      .std()
                      .values)

[       nan        nan        nan        nan        nan        nan
        nan 0.05773503        nan        nan        nan        nan
        nan        nan 0.36055513]
```